# Simple combinatorics question regarding choosing 1 flavour and 2 toppings from 4 flavours and 6 toppings.

Tags: combinatorics

A yoghurt shop has four different flavours and six different toppings. If a customer wanted to get one flavour and two different toppings, how many combinations could she get?

Could someone explain why the following logic doesn’t work?:

The customer has $4$ options for the flavour, then $6$ options for the first topping and $5$ options for the second topping (as it has to be different). So the total number of options is $4(5)(6)=120$. However, this is not correct, could someone explain the flaw in my thinking?

Comment: If the first topping and second topping switch places, are the outcomes the same or different? It all depends on that.

Comment: Ah ok, they will be the same, so there are only 15 ways to arrange the toppings. So 15(4)=60, which is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the flavor in $\binom{4}{1} = 4$ ways, the toppings in $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ ways, for a total of $\binom{4}{1} \cdot \binom{6}{2} = 4 \cdot 15 = 60$ ways in all.

You go wrong in that you consider the order of the toppings, toppings A and B is the same as B and A.